# Impossible to match types?

Tags: typescript

How can I make TS recognise `x` as `B`?

```
type A = { __typename: 'A', foo: true }
type B = A & { __typename: 'B' }
type C = A & { __typename: 'C' }

type X = B | C;

const x: X = { __typename: 'B', foo: true }
```

You can play around with it here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUD6rSQHYEMC2EAXFAOQwkA0UAZgPa3HABOArtAL4BQm0AQgrCgAyZGgzgIuAsRK8SULjygBhAXBEp0PKUVLL5XbhKgANAfwA+KgNydOAY1pYAzsCgAPYmcSbx2fLqylDT0jKwcnEA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type doesn't really make sense, because B is actually:

```
type B = { __typename: 'A', foo: true } & { __typename: 'B' };
```

It's not possible for __typename to be both the string `A` and the string `B` at the same time, so nothing will match with this type.

Comment: Gotcha. Unfortunately thats how https://graphql-code-generator.com works with interfaces and unions :(—Thanks!

Comment: @CentaurWarchief can you show an example of such impossible types coming out of that site?  Seems like it would be a bug there or at least a design limitation.

Comment: Ha—you know what? I just updated the packages and seems to be fixed. Now they're not adding __typename to interfaces. In the older version I was using they were!

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really want to move ahead, then I guess you can just cast it to type X again to silent TypeScript. However as @Evert mentioned, the type doesn't really make sense.

```
type A = { __typename: 'A', foo: true }
type B = A & { __typename: 'B' }
type C = A & { __typename: 'C' }

type X = B | C;

const x: X = <X>{ __typename: 'B', foo: true }

console.log(x.__typename)
```